# How to force line break when showing the content in HTML and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I need a line break when loading the content of the "Mensagem" field that is received by the "message" class: "<% = player.Message%>", but all the loaded text is being presented on on a single line. 
The consultation is carried out in a Mysql bank. 
The Project is done in Javascript. 
How is showing: player.Mensagem = "Line 1 Line 2 Line 3 "
How i need:
player.Mensagem = "
Line 1
Line 2 
Line 3 "

```
<form class="add-player-form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <ul id="chat">
        <li class="you">
            <div class="entete">
                <span class="status green"></span>
                <input type="hidden" id="Celular" name="Celular" value="<%= player.Celular %>">
                <input type="hidden" id="NomeCompleto" name="NomeCompleto" value="<%= player.NomeCompleto %>">

                <h2><%= player.Celular %></h2>
                <h3>10:12AM, Today</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="triangle"></div>
            <div class="message">
                <%= player.Mensagem %>
            </div>
        </li>
</form>
```

Very thanks!

Comment: what framework are you using for the handlebars, you can pretty much loop through the variable by splitting it with (" ") and add a br tag in the html

Comment: I am using "ejs".
Please, how to split this?

Comment: Inside a double-quoted string, use `"\n"` -- or better yet, use template literals when building your string: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals. (Or, of course, if you can insert HTML elements between strings, you have the option to use `<br />` elements.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace(/\n/g, '<br>')` and `<%-` to output the unescaped value into the template

```
<%- player.Mensagem.replace(/\n/g, '<br>') %>
```

But if there is any possibility the value could contain html code you should escape it to be safe against code injection.

```
<%- ejs.escapeXML(player.Mensagem).replace(/\n/g, '<br>') %>
```

Or you can keep the template tag as is and use CSS `white-space: pre-wrap` on your "message" class or the div element.